# ValueError:keeps appearing and doesn't go away

Tags: python

The error that I have keeps appearing and I don't know what is wrong.
The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  file "pipeline52", line 9, in <module>
    dag = datetime.strptime(line, "%d/%m/%Y")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datatime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 346, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end();])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

The code I have is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

with open("table.txt", "r") as file:
  for line in file:
     if (line != ""):
        print(line)
        dag = datetime.strptime(line, "%d/%m/%Y")
        print(dag)
```

the date is a list of dates:

```
23/02/2002
28/07/1976
24/03/2018
03/11/1980
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error `ValueError: unconverted data remains:` and the fact your inputs come from a file, it is almost guaranteed you have `\n` after every date, so you have to `.strip` it:

```
dag = datetime.strptime(line.strip(), "%d/%m/%Y")
```